# Is $0_R$ the only element in a ring to give $0_R$ if multiplied by some element of the ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For all elements of a ring $(S,*,{\circ})$, $0_R$ being the identity of $*$, ${\forall}x{\in}S:0_R{\circ}x=0_R$.

Is it the only element of $S$ with that property, or can there be more?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $0$ and $0'$ both satisfy this property, then $$0 = 0 \circ 0' = 0'.$$

EDIT: This uses the "stronger" two-sided property $0 \circ x = 0 = x \circ 0$, which actually follows from the axioms of a ring.

Comment: Wouldn't $0{\circ}0'$ be $0$?

Comment: It would be, but it would also be $0'$. So they are the same thing (assuming the same commutativity condition in this answer)

Comment: Actually $0\circ x =0=x\circ 0$ holds in any ring.

Comment: I still don't see how your equation works in noncommutative rings: $0$ multiplied by something gives you itself, so the resukt of this equation is $0$. Besides, $0{\circ}0'=0$ and $0'{\circ}0=0$, so this particular equation will always be commutative.

Comment: @Hvghnn The point is that A.P. assumes in his answer that $0'$ is also absorbant for $\circ$, that is, $0'\circ x=0'=x\circ 0'$ for all $x\in S$. Notice that since $0_R$ is known to be absorbant on both sides, any absorbant (even on one side) has to be $0_R$.